# What's the logic behind the SomeArray.sort ( function() { ... } ) statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, random, shuffle

```
var array = [3,9,23,76,1,54,21,12,0,9,2];
var shuffled = array.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
console.log(shuffled);
```

I'm aware of the results, and also satified with them.

The code above returns a shuffled order of the elements of my array.

I'm puzzled by why it results in that output.

What's the point of the function inside of the `.sort` and how does it contribute to the output?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: sorry, which category it would go for,so?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I can go ahead and make the change myself, but it's worth brining the point up. What did you really save by reducing four letters in "Whatever"?

Comment: Fisher-Yates is a much better shuffling algorithm, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function actually takes two arguments, which are 2 items from the array. The purpose is to compare these elements and return a number.
If the number is positive, the second item should be before the first item.
If the number is 0 or negative, the second item should be after the first item.

```
[0,1].sort(function(a,b){return  1;}); // [1, 0], reverses order
[0,1].sort(function(a,b){return  0;}); // [0, 1], does nothing
[0,1].sort(function(a,b){return -1;}); // [0, 1], does nothing
```

In each case of the example above, `a === 0` and `b === 1`.

---

### Edit for step by step output

To see step-by-step what is happening with an ascending sort on `[1,3,2,4,4,0]`, one can write a function which logs exactly what happens each step

```
arr = [1,3,2,4,4,0];
arr.sort(function(a,b){ // ascending order sort
    var result = a-b,
    str = '';
    if(result > 0) str = 'so swapping';
    else if(result === 0) str = 'so ignoring'
    else str = 'so continuing';
    console.log('with [ '+arr.join(', ')+' ]','comparing',a,'to',b,'resulting in',result, str);
    return result;
});
console.log('resulting in [ '+arr.join(', ')+' ]');
```

which outputs

```
with [ 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 0 ] comparing 1 to 3 resulting in -2 so continuing
with [ 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 0 ] comparing 3 to 2 resulting in 1 so swapping
with [ 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0 ] comparing 1 to 2 resulting in -1 so continuing
with [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0 ] comparing 3 to 4 resulting in -1 so continuing
with [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0 ] comparing 4 to 4 resulting in 0 so ignoring
with [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0 ] comparing 4 to 0 resulting in 4 so swapping
with [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4 ] comparing 4 to 0 resulting in 4 so swapping
with [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4 ] comparing 3 to 0 resulting in 3 so swapping
with [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 ] comparing 2 to 0 resulting in 2 so swapping
with [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4 ] comparing 1 to 0 resulting in 1 so swapping
resulting in [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 ]
```

---

For completeness, probability table for shuffle algorithm in original question (estimates, based on 500,000 trials for each index), X is starting index

```
 x     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 0 |  8.0,  8.0,  6.2,  6.6,  9.2, 10.8,  9.3,  6.6,  6.2,  9.7, 18.8
 1 |  4.5,  4.6,  7.8, 12.2, 16.9, 12.9, 11.4, 10.7,  8.7,  6.1,  3.6
 2 | 15.5, 15.5, 10.3,  5.9,  3.7,  3.8,  5.7,  8.3, 10.6, 11.7,  8.5
 3 | 10.4, 10.3, 13.4, 10.2,  7.0,  6.5,  7.8,  9.4,  9.7,  8.8,  6.0
 4 |  6.4,  6.3, 10.7, 15.4, 11.4,  9.5,  9.6,  9.9,  8.9,  6.9,  4.4
 5 | 16.1, 16.1, 10.9,  7.7,  7.4,  7.6,  6.2,  4.4,  4.1,  6.5, 12.5
 6 |  4.7,  4.7,  7.1,  9.7, 12.6, 16.3, 13.6, 11.9,  9.2,  6.1,  3.6
 7 |  6.0,  6.0,  7.7,  8.9,  9.4, 10.9, 14.0, 13.6, 11.2,  7.4,  4.3
 8 |  8.4,  8.3,  9.1,  8.6,  7.3,  6.7,  8.2, 11.6, 13.8, 10.8,  6.7
 9 | 11.5, 11.4, 10.1,  7.6,  5.0,  3.7,  4.2,  6.7, 10.9, 15.8, 12.6
10 |  8.0,  8.1,  6.2,  6.6,  9.2, 10.9,  9.2,  6.6,  6.1,  9.8, 18.8
```

Comment: So, you mean that the items are compared in pairs? Pair by pair? like array[1] to array[2] and then array[1] to array[3], giving then the directions to the output?

Comment: Yes, it does that if `arr[1]` is to be swapped with `arr[2]`, if not, it could compare `arr[2]` to `arr[3]` and only compare `arr[1]` with `arr[3]` if `arr[2]` and `arr[3]` are going to be swapped. This saves having to do every possible comparison.

Comment: I hope this edit which gives a step-by-step log of what is happening shows exactly how the array is changed

Comment: From this you may have realised that your shuffle function doesn't give each item the same probability of being moved to a certain index (so not 1/n, n array length), but something like a bell curve around their starting index

Comment: added table of percentages for your `shuffle` algorithm, left-most column is starting index, other columns are % probability that is where the shuffle sends them

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the purpose of the sort is to randomly arrange the items in the list. The anonymous function to the sort() method is either going to return a positive or negative value, which is precisely what the callback is supposed to do.

The sort callback is supposed to be used to compare two items, and return either -1, 0, or -1 for less than, equality, and greater than, respectively.

Now there's probably another discussion about whether that is a good way to randomize, because the comparing function could return different values for the same two objects on discrete calls.....

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `sort` is a sorting callback, it is a function that supposed to take two values being sorted as arguments and return negative, 0, or positive depending if first value compared is lesser, equal, or greater than second.

In your particular example, this callback completely ignores actual values compared and instead generates a random number with `Math.random`, that returns a value in range 0 .. 1 and subtracts it from 0.5 to change resulting range to -0.5 .. 0.5. This makes sort randomly assume one value being lesser or greater than another and ends in generating list shuffled randomly instead of sorted by some "real" condition.

Comment: Thank you, really good explanation, but still...is this comparsion process like a loop? That's why it needs a function not an simple integer? And the arguments choice is made by the index ascending sequence?

Comment: Discussing sorting algorithms is quite a long topic, which you can [check out on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), but most of them boil down to selecting pairs of values from array being sorted and reordering them according to comparison result. Since you can't possibly build in language all the possible criteria to decide which value is greater and which is lesser, most sorting implementation simply allow you to specify custom function to decide.